# Understanding Theorem 5.4. Conway functional analysis

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-explanation

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2625690/isomorphic-hilbert-spaces-iff-they-have-the-same-dimension) in the OP is theorem 5.4. and proof.

A. In the **fifth** line of the proof why $||h||=||\hat{h}||$? The RHS is norm of an operator which is the supremum of all $|<h, e>|$.

B. In **7th** line of proof why ran(U) is dense, even though I understand the statement before that?

C. Later (not included in the proof /picture) he claims if E basis of H and F basis of K have same cardinality then $l^2(E)$ is isomorphic to $l^2(F)$. How this is concluded?

Added: Please let me know how I should edit this post to improve it. I can't add my attempts because it's not an exercise it's a proof of a book that I couldn't understand three details. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A.**

> Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $x\in H$. Set $f:H\to\mathbb{C}$ as $f(y)=\langle y,x\rangle$. Then $\|f\|=\|x\|$.

Proof: By Cauchy-Schwarz we have that $|f(y)|\leq\|y\|\|x\|$ for all $y\in H$, so $\|f\|\leq \|x\|$. On the other hand, $\|x\|^2=\langle x,x\rangle=|f(x)|\leq\|f\|\|x\|$, so $\|x\|\leq\|f\|$.

**B.** We have the map $U:H\to\ell^2(E)$ defined by $Ux=\langle\cdot,x\rangle$. You say that you understand that the range of $U$ contains every function $f\in\ell^2(E)$ that satisfy $f(e)=0$ for all except finitely many $e\in E$. Now we want to use that to show that the range of $U$ is dense in $\ell^2(E)$:

Let $f\in\ell^2(E)$ and $\varepsilon>0$. We will find a function $g\in\ell^2(E)$ such that $g(e)=0$ for all except finitely many $e\in E$ so that $\|f-g\|_{\ell^2(E)}<\varepsilon$. Since all such functions are contained in the range of $U$, we will have that the range of $U$ is dense.

Since $f\in\ell^2(E)$ we have that $\sum_{e\in E}|f(e)|^2<\infty$. **By definition** this means that $$\sup\{\sum_{e\in F}|f(e)^2|: F\text{ is a finite subset of }E\} $$
is finite. In general, if $S$ is a set of reals and $c=\sup(S)$, then for any $\varepsilon>0$ we can find an element $x\in S$ so that $c-x<\varepsilon$. Therefore, applying this, we can find a finite subset $F\subset E$ so that
$$\bigg(\sum_{e\in E}|f(e)|^2-\sum_{e\in F}|f(e)|^2\bigg)<\varepsilon$$

Now consider the function $g:E\to\mathbb{C}$ defined by $g(e)=f(e)$ for $e\in F$ and $g(e)=0$ for $e\not\in F$. Then $g$ is in the form we want and we have that
$$\|f-g\|_{\ell^2(E)}=\sum_{e\in E}|f(e)-g(e)|^2=\sum_{e\in E\setminus F}|f(e)|^2=\sum_{e\in E}|f(e)|^2-\sum_{e\in F}|f(e)|^2<\varepsilon$$

**C.** I will only sketch this, but I am sure that you can fill in the details. Assume that $H,K$ are two Hilbert spaces with orthonormal bases $E$ and $G$ respectively so that $E$ and $G$ are sets of the same cardinality. This means that we can find a function $f:E\to G$ that is 1-1 and onto. Now define an operator
$$V:H\to K$$
first on the orthonormal bases and then extend linearly and continuously. For $e\in E$, simply define $V(e)=f(e)\in G$. After extending, the operator $V$ will actually be
$$Vh=\sum_{e\in E}\langle h,e\rangle f(e)$$
Sinve $V$ is an operator that sends an ONB onto an ONB in a one-to-one way, it is a unitary operator (i.e. it preserves inner product and is onto), i.e. a Hilbert space isomorphism.