# Hilbert spaces with same dimension are isometrically isomorph?

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Is it true that two infinit dimensional Hilbert spaces are isometricly isomorphic if they have the same dimension in terms of a hamel basis?

Comment: The textbook excerpt in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2625690/81360) indicates that this is true if they have the same dimension in in the sense of a **Schauder basis**. The question that remains, then, is whether two spaces with the same "Schauder dimension" also have the same "Hamel dimension". I believe that the answer to this is "yes".

Answer (score 1):

I claim that if $H$ is a Hilbert space with an orthonormal basis of cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$ then $H$ is algebraically isomorphic (i.e. has a Hamel basis of the same cardinality) to $\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$. Since these are obviously not isometrically isomorphic since isometric isomorphisms preserve the cardinality of orthonormal bases, this answers your question in the negative.

First note that since every element of $H$ can be written as $\sum_{i \in I} \alpha_i v_i$ where $\{v_i: i \in I\}$ is an orthonormal basis and $\alpha_i \neq 0$ for only countably many $i$, one has that
$$|H| \le (2^{\aleph_0})^{\aleph_0} \cdot (2^{\aleph_0})^{\aleph_0} = 2^{\aleph_0}$$
so an upper bound on the algebraic dimension of $H$ is $2^{\aleph_0}$. Since $H$ has an orthonormal basis of cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$, we find that its algebraic dimension is $2^{\aleph_0}$.

Similarly, $\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$ has algebraic dimension at most $2^{\aleph_0}$. To see that it has algebraic dimension $2^{\aleph_0}$, we construct a linearly independent subset of cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$ inspired by the construction of $\mathbb{R}$ by Dedekind cuts.

Fix a bijection $\phi : \mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{N}$. For $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$, let $A_\lambda = \{ q \in \mathbb{Q}: q < \lambda\}$ be the corresponding Dedekind cut. Then consider the sequences

$$ x_n^{(\lambda)} = \begin{cases} 0 \text{ if } \phi^{-1}(n) \not \in A_\lambda \\
n^{-1} \text{ otherwise.} \end{cases}$$
which are clearly elements of $\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$ since $\sum_{n \ge 1} |x_n^{(\lambda)}|^2 \le \sum_{n \ge 1} n^{-2} < \infty$.

For any finite subset of $\{x^{(\lambda)}: \lambda \in \mathbb{R}\}$, say $x^{(\lambda_1)}, \cdots, x^{(\lambda_k)}$ with $\lambda_1 < \cdots < \lambda_k$, pick $q \in (\lambda_{k-1}, \lambda_k)$ and let $n_q = \phi(q)$. Then $x_{n_q}^{(\lambda_k)} \neq 0$ whilst $x_{n_q}^{(\lambda_j)} = 0$ for $j = 0, \cdots, k-1$ which proves linear independence. Hence $\{x^{(\lambda)}: \lambda \in \mathbb{R}\}$ is a linearly independent subset of $\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$ of cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$ as desired.